# How can I get latest records in Amazon Kinesis consumer when working with Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-kinesis

I am using AWS Javascript SDK to consume from Kinesis Data Stream. I want to get latest records in the shard.

When I am giving ShardIterator Type as "LATEST" I am not getting any records back. However, when I am using "TRIM_HORIZON", I am getting all the records back.

```
kinesis.describeStream(describeParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);    // an error occurred
            }
            else {
                var getParams = {
                    ShardId: data.StreamDescription.Shards[0].ShardId,
                    ShardIteratorType: "TRIM_HORIZON",     //get oldest package
                    StreamName: streamName,
                };

                if(shardIteratorType){
                    console.log("you have passed some shardIteratorType:" + shardIteratorType);
                    getParams.ShardIteratorType = shardIteratorType;
                }

                kinesis.getShardIterator(getParams, function(err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error in getShardIterator()");
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("calling getRecord with shard iterator");
                        // Get records from the Kinesis stream
                        getRecord(result.ShardIterator);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

function getRecord(shard_iterator) {
    console.log("getRecord was called.");
    var getRecParams = {
        ShardIterator: shard_iterator
    };

    kinesis.getRecords(getRecParams, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error in getRecords() from the Kinesis stream.");
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            try {

            if(result.Records.length > 0) {
                    // Loop through all the packages
               for(var i = 0; i < result.Records.length; i++) {
                   if(result.Records[i] != undefined) {
                        var getData = JSON.parse( decodeURIComponent
(escape(result.Records[i].Data)));
                        console.log(getData);
                        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
                        var row = table.insertRow(0);
                        var j = i + 1 ;
                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);


                        cell1.innerHTML = getData ;

                    }
                }
            }
            } catch(err) {
                console.log("Error parsing the package.");
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I would expect to get only the latest records instead of all the history upon using "LATEST" instead of "TRIM_HORIZON" for shard iterator type. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From the documenation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html

> In the request, you can specify the shard iterator type AT_TIMESTAMP to read records from an arbitrary point in time, TRIM_HORIZON to cause ShardIterator to point to the last untrimmed record in the shard in the system (the oldest data record in the shard), or LATEST so that you always read the most recent data in the shard.

Here the LATEST implies "right now" skipping all the records between latest checkpoint and now.

Using LATEST as the shard iterator type, you can think that it reads the records that come right after using the shard iterator that is returned by getShardIterator function.

You can refer below as an example how it works with 'LATEST':

```
kinesis.describeStream(describeParams, (err, streamData) => {
    // Skipping error handling

    kinesis.getShardIterator(getShardIteratorParams, (err, shardIterData) => {
        let shardIterator = shardIterData.ShardIterator;

        // Keep reading records from the stream
        while (true) {
            let getRecParams = {
                ShardIterator: shardIterator
            };
            kinesis.getRecords(getRecParams, (err, recData) => {
                // Skipping error handling

                if (recData.Records.length > 0) {
                   // Do something

                   shardIterator = recData.NextShardIterator;
                }
            });
            // Break if you need
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe that `sleep(200)` is required in the `while (true)` loop. That's because the default API limit for `getRecords` is 5 calls per second ([reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html)).

Comment: Also, `shardIterator = recData.NextShardIterator` should be out of the `(recData.Records.length > 0)` condition block.